# Executing algorithm fix geometries stuck at 92%

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3, geometry, loading

I want to fix the geometry of some shapefiles but the loading is stuck at 92 percent for over half an hour right now. The shapefile is quite small and had 2 invalid polygons and 11 valid polygons when the validity was checked.  Does anyone know why this loading can get stuck/or how to fix this?

[image: Fix geometry loading]

Comment: We definitely need some more details on this. How large is you shapefile? How many features? Which type? What have you tried?

Comment: What were the issues you got when running "Check validity" and how did you run it (QGIS or Geos method in particular)?